# I have a very old Dell XPS a2010 computer. The computer starts up and displays the Dell logo and from there it goes to a Windows recovery error

Tags: windows, windows-vista

I have a very old Dell XPS a2010 computer. The computer starts up and displays the Dell logo and from there it goes to a Windows recovery error.

Nothing seems to be working. Endless Windows recovery error Windows loop.

I have tried removing battery, and reinstalling, tried CMOS jumper wires and nothing seems to help.

Comment: Sounds like a disk error

Comment: Disk as per above.  Get the Dell Hardware Diagnostics on bootable USB and test.

Answer (score 3):

The Dell XPS a2010 likely came with Windows Vista, or perhaps Windows 7. Those operating systems have not been supported for a *long* while, and it is doubtful the PC would be fast enough to run Windows 10 (which reaches end of life in [Oct, 2025](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/lifecycle/products/windows-10-home-and-pro)), and certainly could not support Windows 11, with TPM requirements.

Your best course of action would be to salvage data, if it's of use, and to wipe the disk *if it's still in good shape* (check S.M.A.R.T. BTW, I've had HDD that last 12 years, and some 2 years) and install a current operating system. Here are some ways to do so.

##### Salvage Data

- If you already have disk imaging tools, such as [Macrium Rescue Environment](https://www.macrium.com/blog/the-macrium-rescue-environment-cca57a4ebc61) or an [alternative](https://alternativeto.net/software/rescuezilla/), boot from that and image the disk to an external drive,
- Or create a [Ubuntu Live USB](https://itsfoss.com/create-live-usb-of-ubuntu-in-windows/) or similar live Linux distro, boot directly from USB, and use either dd or [Ubuntu's *Disks* utility](https://www.makeuseof.com/tag/manage-ubuntu-hdd-disk-utility/) to image the drive to external media.

##### Install a New Operating System

- If you've made live Ubuntu media, test the OS to see if you like it. If so, use *Disks* to remove *all* partitions, leaving the drive empty, and install Ubuntu directly from that media.
- Alternatively, select another OS and test it before installing.

My experience with older 32-bit computers, as well as with 64-bit machines comparable to that Dell, is that

- Linux can be installed in a smaller amount of drive space than Windows,
- Runs applications faster,
- And is still supported, unlike Windows Vista, 7, 8 and (soon) 10.

Comment: You forgot "*Install a new disk!* " Probably there is still metal spinning in that machine... a new disk is advisable even if the old one were not defective.

Comment: Small correction: current EOL date for Win 10 is just under *two* years away: Oct 2025, according to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/lifecycle/products/windows-10-home-and-pro